# PHP - How do I get a specific value of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a beginner in PHP, so basically I have an array with no key specified and only values which are arrays. 
I want to get the name of people who are going to the springbreak (== true).
I've tried this but it's not working ...

```
$liste = [
  ['name' => 'Elsa', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
  ['name' => 'Chris', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
  ['name' => 'Zob', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false' ],
  ['name' => 'Ken', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
  ['name' => 'Ryan', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false' ],
  ['name' => 'Tenta', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ]

];

  foreach($liste as $line){
        foreach($line as $value){
          if ($value['springbreak'] == true)
               echo $value['name'];
        }
  }
```

the output should be : Elsa,Chris,Ken,Tenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why your existing code doesn't work?**

Because you used unnecessary **two** `foreach()` whereas a **single** `foreach()` 
will do the trick. Another reason is you're comparing like this `$line['springbreak'] == true` which should be `$line['springbreak'] == 'true'`

So, with your existing code. Let's try,

```
foreach($liste as $line){
    if ($line['springbreak'] == 'true')
        echo $line['name'];
}
```

**Why not simple** `foreach()` **loop and** `implode()` **to join the name where springbreak** is `true`?

```
<?php
$liste = [
    ['name' => 'Elsa', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
    ['name' => 'Chris', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
    ['name' => 'Zob', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false' ],
    ['name' => 'Ken', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
    ['name' => 'Ryan', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false' ],
    ['name' => 'Tenta', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ]
];
$names = [];
foreach($liste as $list){
    if($list['springbreak']=='true'){
        $names[] = $list['name'];
    }
}
echo implode(',',$names);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Elsa,Chris,Ken,Tenta
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/B7Bo6

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter), [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map), and [`join`](http://www.php.net/join):

```
<?php
$liste = [
  ['name' => 'Elsa', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'true'],
  ['name' => 'Chris', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true'],
  ['name' => 'Zob', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false'],
  ['name' => 'Ken', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true'],
  ['name' => 'Ryan', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false'],
  ['name' => 'Tenta', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true']
];

// Filter to only keep values with springbreak to true
$springbreak_only = array_filter($liste, function($entry) { return $entry['springbreak'] === 'true'; });

// Grab the names (and ditch the rest)
$springbreak_names = array_map(function($entry) { return $entry['name']; }, $springbreak_only);

// Output the comma-separated names
echo join(', ', $springbreak_names);
```

[Online snippet](https://3v4l.org/E77vm)

Alternative with [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/array_reduce) (will only loop once):

```
$springbreak_names = array_reduce($liste, function($springbreak_names, $entry) {
  if ($entry['springbreak'] === 'true')
    $springbreak_names[] = $entry['name'];
  return $springbreak_names;
}, []);

echo join(', ', $springbreak_names);
```

See @don't angry me's answer for another simple solution, less functional but also more straightforward.

**Note**: you should probably use the boolean value `true` instead of `'true'` (string) when you can.

Comment: **array_reduce()** way seems promising to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot if statement.

```
foreach($liste as $line){
    foreach($line as $value){
        if($value['springbreak'] === 'true'){
            echo $value['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
<?php

    $liste = [
        ['name' => 'Elsa', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
        ['name' => 'Chris', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
        ['name' => 'Zob', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false' ],
        ['name' => 'Ken', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ],
        ['name' => 'Ryan', 'job' => 'Student', 'springbreak' => 'false' ],
        ['name' => 'Tenta', 'job' => 'Teacher', 'springbreak' => 'true' ]

    ];


    $going_to_springbreak = array();

    //Check every item
    foreach($liste as $line){
        //Check first if the 'springbreak' is true
        if($line['springbreak'] == 'true'){
            //Then add the name of that item to the new array
            $going_to_springbreak[] = $line['name'];

            //OR you can add the entire item to the new array if you want to use the other values
            //$going_to_springbreak[] = $line;
        }
    }

    var_dump($going_to_springbreak)

?>
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Elsa"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "Chris"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "Ken"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "Tenta"
    }
```

On a final note, I would highly recommed to store the 'true' or 'false' value as a primitive value, so:

```
'springbreak' => true
```